# getting EmailAddresses values exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to come up with a mailbox statistics with some useful information. I am using this below and all works okay except the emailaddresses part.

```
$mailboxStatistics = $allMailboxes | foreach {
    $mailboxType = $_.RecipientTypeDetails
    $OU = $_.OrganizationalUnit
    $UPN = $_.UserPrincipalName
    $primaryEmail = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
    $EmailAddresses = @{Name='EmailAddresses'; Expression={$_.EmailAddresses -join ","}}
    Get-MailboxStatistics -identity $_.identity | Select-Object DisplayName,LastLogonTime,LastLogOffTime,ItemCount,TotalItemSize,@{label='MailboxType';expression={$mailboxType}},@{label='OU';expression={$OU}},@{label='UPN';expression={$UPN}},@{label='PrimarySMTP';expression={$PrimaryEmail}},@{label='EmailAddresses';expression={$EmailAddresses}}
}
```

the output gives this value for emailaddresses column. Can any body let me know how to fix?
"System.Collections.Hashtable"

Answer (score 0):

Because you've turned it into a Hastable: `@{}`. Assume you want a comma separated string, if so, the below should work:

```
$mailboxStatistics = $allMailboxes | foreach {
    $mailboxType = $_.RecipientTypeDetails
    $OU = $_.OrganizationalUnit
    $UPN = $_.UserPrincipalName
    $primaryEmail = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
    $EmailAddresses = $_.EmailAddresses -join ","
    Get-MailboxStatistics -identity $_.identity | Select-Object DisplayName,LastLogonTime,LastLogOffTime,ItemCount,TotalItemSize,@{label='MailboxType';expression={$mailboxType}},@{label='OU';expression={$OU}},@{label='UPN';expression={$UPN}},@{label='PrimarySMTP';expression={$PrimaryEmail}},@{label='EmailAddresses';expression={$EmailAddresses}}
}
```